# Execution of Batch class

Tags: apex

I have the below batch class apex code. How can I execute this class in apex?

```
global class X implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('select JDE_ship_to_account_no__c from account');
    }

    global  void finish(database.batchablecontext context) { }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        set<string> shipToVals = new set<String>();
        for(Account record: scope) {
            shipToVals.add(record.jde_ship_to_account_no__c);
        }
        AggregateResult[] ar = [SELECT jde_ship_to_account_no__c
            from account where jde_ship_to_account_no__c in :shipToVals
            group by jde_ship_to_account_no__c
            having count(jde_ship_to_account_no__c) > 1];
            // More queries/processing here
    }
}
```

Comment: like classname.function name()

Comment: Database.executeBatch(new X());

Answer (score 3):

To invoke a batch class you will first need to instantiate it and then call the Database.executeBatch within the instance. Something like

```
MyBatchClass X = new MyBatchClass();
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(X);
```

Hope this helps. Again, please see the Trailhead modules related to [Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/asynchronous_apex).

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
X batch = new X ();
Database.ExecuteBatch (batch);
```

For more info, see: [The Apex Batch Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_batch_3.htm)

I would strongly advise renaming your class to something meaningful.

Lastly, your class is currently doing nothing. It will just run some queries but it will not modify data in any way. I assume that will be done where your comment currently is.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a scheduler..from there you can call the batch

```
X newBatch = new X();
Database.executeBatch(newBatch);
```

or,

```
X newBatch = new X();
Database.executeBatch(newBatch, 1);
```

// here "1" in the last line means, the batch will process all the records, but 1 record at a time

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer console, click on open anonymous window.
Create an instance of your class.

```
 x obj=new x();
```

now call `database.executebatch();`, it will return an Id. You can use this in future queries.

```
Id batchId = database.executebatch(obj);
```

Your class is now running asynchronously.